# How To Create Custom Transitions?

Tags: d3.js

One way to ask question might be: How do I refactor [this example](http://livecoding.io/5062432) so that it conforms to d3 conventions?  (code included below as well)

That is, rather than writing, as I have:

```
rotateTransition(line1, 90)
```

I would prefer to write something like:

```
line1.transition().attr("rotation-around-origin", 90)
```

So the question is: What is the proper way to extend d3's Transition with a custom transition like the one in my example?  Or: How would I go about monkey-patching "line" selection objects?

BONUS QUESTION: In lines 6-16, I create 2 "line" selection with exactly the same initialization.  Is there a d3 method to duplicate a selection based off another selection?  Something like: `line2 = line1.dup()`

Source code of example linked to above:

```
var centerX = centerY = 50
var radius = 200

var svg = d3.select("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height",600)

var line1 = svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", centerX)
  .attr("y1", centerY)
  .attr("x2", centerX + radius)
  .attr("y2", centerY);

var line2 = svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", centerX)
  .attr("y1", centerY)
  .attr("x2", centerX + radius)
  .attr("y2", centerY);

line1.attr("transform", "translate(100,100) rotate(45 50 50)");

function rotateTransition(line, degrees) {

  var rotationString = function(angle, x1, x2) { return "rotate("+angle+" "+x1+" "+x2+")" };
  var retInterpolator, startAngle = 0, endAngle = degrees;
  var transformStart = line.attr("transform") ? line.attr("transform") : "";
  var curRotation = transformStart.match(/rotate\((\d+) /)

  if (curRotation)
    endAngle = parseInt(curRotation.pop()) + degrees;
  else
    transformStart += rotationString(0,line.attr("x1"),line.attr("y1"));

  var transformEnd = transformStart.replace(/(.*rotate\()(\d+)( .*)/,"$1"+endAngle+"$3")
      console.log(transformStart);
  console.log(transformEnd);
  line.transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attrTween("transform", function() {
    return d3.interpolateString(transformStart, transformEnd);
  })
}

rotateTransition(line1, 90)
rotateTransition(line2, 45)
```

Answer (score 1):

For both of your questions, [have a look here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-call) at d3's `selection.call()` method.

In the case of the line rotation, you wouldn't even have to change `rotateTransition`'s body. You'll just use it like this:

```
line1.call(rotateTransition, 90)
```

Really the only difference is that this approach allows you chain the function calls.

If you feel like digging deeper, for general education, check out the d3 source code for how `d3.svg.axis()` is implemented, because this `call()` method is used in conjunction, when applying an axis to a d3 selection.

Comment: thanks, very helpful.  and i do feel like digging deeper.  followup question for you: using the selection.call() technique to create duplicates isn't a terrific approach, because you'll have to create separate helper methods for each svg elm (since they have different attributes) and then do something like `s.call(dup_line)` or `s.call(dup_circle)`.  what i really want is to extend the behavior of selection, so i can do `s.dup` on any selection and the correct thing happens based on type.  would this require altering d3's core, or is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: @Jonah What I had in mind for your 2nd question wasn't quite dup'ing, but rather just putting the code that sets the `attr`s into a function. So it'd be something like: `var line1 = svg.append("line").call(prepareLine);`

Comment: @Jonah Dup'ing like you describe has a challenge that I'm not sure what it takes to get around (aside from the one you bring up, about needing to know the element type). It's the fact that if you're cloning a dom element, the cloned element isn't attached to the DOM. In jQuery, it doesn't matter; an element can exist without being part of the DOM. In d3, I don't know if that's possible, or what it takes to do so. The only way I've ever seen elements being create in d3 is via the `append` method, which by definition, requires a parent.

Comment: Re: your 1st comment, I was suggesting the `s.dup` would be shorthand for `<parent elm of s>.append("<type of s>").call(<prepareTypeOfS>)`.  I could see providing other optional arguments too, but this case should cover 90% of use-cases I think.